# where is the specification for VHD 1.3?

Tags: vhd, vdi

I am looking for the higher versions of the VHD file format specification. I found a reference to 1.3 in [BLKTAP](https://github.com/xapi-project/blktap/blob/a8aef5c31598a49dfad8bbe2bff89554a92fe2b8/include/vhd.h#L88), but I can't find the document with google.

There is an old Microsoft .doc file from 2006 around the internet describing the version 1.0, but I am trying to interface with xenserver.